# Why "Least consecutive subsequence" algorithm have O(n) running time complexity when we are using hashSet?

Tags: java, algorithm, set, big-o

This java code is taken from geeks for geeks which is to find the longest consecutive subsequence and it says the running time complexity of the code is O(n). But I couldn't understand why O(n) and not O(n<sup>2</sup>) as it contains a nested loop.

```
// Java program to find longest
// consecutive subsequence
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class ArrayElements {
    // Returns length of the longest
    // consecutive subsequence
    static int findLongestConseqSubseq(int arr[], int n)
    {
        HashSet<Integer> S = new HashSet<Integer>();
        int ans = 0;

        // Hash all the array elements
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            S.add(arr[i]);

        // check each possible sequence from the start
        // then update optimal length
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        {
            // if current element is the starting
            // element of a sequence
            if (!S.contains(arr[i] - 1))
            {
                // Then check for next elements
                // in the sequence
                int j = arr[i];
                while (S.contains(j))
                    j++;

                // update optimal length if this
                // length is more
                if (ans < j - arr[i])
                    ans = j - arr[i];
            }
        }
        return ans;
    }

    // Driver Code
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int arr[] = { 1, 9, 3, 10, 4, 20, 2 };
        int n = arr.length;
        System.out.println(
            "Length of the Longest consecutive subsequence is "
            + findLongestConseqSubseq(arr, n));
    }
}
// This code is contributed by Aakash Hasija
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `S.contains(j)` is `O(1)` because we know that checking for the containment in an hashed set is constant.
- `j++` is obviously `O(1)`.

Therefore, the cost of the whole *inner loop* is `O(1)`.

Thus, the cost of the *outer loop* is `O(n*1)` = `O(n)`.

Answer (score 1):

Because this condition guarantees that it is the beginning of the sequence

```
if (!S.contains(arr[i] - 1))
```

So, all elements of current sequence will not be counted next time.
The worst case is when all elements are consecutive. For example, `[1,2,3,4,5]`.
Time complexity is O(n) for the first element, O(1) for other elements.

- n => once
- 1 + ... + 1 => n times

O(n) = n + n = 2n = n